# Why my overriding method of toString() has to be public?

Tags: java, object-to-string

I am new to Java and I am learning the basics. I was studying the `toString` method and how to override it in my own classes. I am just wondering why has `toString` to be `public`? is it because it is defined so in the `Object` class?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3

Comment: You can always call a private method from within `toString()`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From official Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> **Modifiers**
>
> The access specifier for an overriding method **can allow more, but not less, access than the overridden method**. For example, a protected instance method in the superclass can be made public, but not private, in the subclass.

This because inheritance creates an [IS-A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relation between two classes, for which the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) must be valid. Without having the previous constraint that would be impossible to enforce.

Comment: The LSP requires that casting an object to a base type makes it behave as a base type, so any object which overrides a method must do so in such a fashion as to comply with the base-class contract.  *That does not imply that the method must be useful, however*.  If the `Woozler` contract specifies that `Fnorble()` is not required to do anything useful if `CanFnorble()` returns false, and if sealed class `Moozler` (derived from `Woozler`) cannot `Fnorble()`, then it would be just as well to forbid attempts to call `Fnorble()` on an object which is known to be a `Moozler`.

Answer (score 22):

Think about it:  You subclass Gizmo with MyGizmo.  This means that any place that a Gizmo can be used, you can use a MyGizmo in it's place.  If some program does `gizmoObject.toString()` then that should work even if gizmoObject is not a Gizmo but a MyGizmo.

In particular, `toString` is used for printing & dumping objects and needs to be accessible on all objects.

Comment: +1, for the same reason as @OliCharlesworth. It is not just an arbitrary rule.

Answer (score 14):

When you override any method, the visibility of the override must be at least as visible as the base method.

Answer (score 2):

When you override any method, the visibility of the override must be **equal** or **more** than the visibility of the base method

Answer (score 1):

When overriding a method, you should declare the visibility of overridden method as the the one in the base class or wider.

Here is a note about the overriding rules I wrote it myself as a reference to me:

> /* Access Modifiers */
>
> 1- Access modifier in child should be same or greater (the sequence:
>   public - protected - default (package-private) - private).    Access
>   modifier in parent should not be private. If a child don't have access
>   to the parent's method, then overriding the method    without the
>   @Override annotation will consider it as a new method.
>
> /* Return Types */
>
> 2- Return type in child should be the same class or sub-class.
>
> /* Exceptions */
>
> 3- If the parent's method throws checked exception, then the child's
>   method can:    a- throw the same exception or sub-class.    b- not to
>   throw any exceptions.    c- throw runtime exceptions.
>
> 4- If the parent's method throws unchecked exception, then the child's
>   method can:    a- not to throw any exceptions.    b- throw runtime
>   exceptions.
>
> 5- If the parnet's method does not throw exception, then the child's
>   method can:    a- not to throw any exceptions.    b- throw runtime
>   exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are **overriding** a method, you must define it as the prototype method or more than that.

Comment: -1: Beside the point (`toString` must be `public`, `protected` won't do), and incorrect (you can override a method declared with access modifier with another method without access modifier if it is in the same package)

Answer (score 0):

when you override an sub class method visibility must be wider than parent class.

Wider to strict order:

public
default
protected
private